# Trying to sort my result of foreach loop on postcount

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

Trying to get top posters sorted on their post count obtained from an Invision powerboard API (forum software). Can't figure out how to sort this echo of my foreach loop.

```
$curl = curl_init( $communityUrl . '/core/members/' );
curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH    => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD     => "{$apiKey}:"
    ) );
$response = curl_exec( $curl );
$data = json_decode($response, true);
$count = 0;
foreach($data as $member) {     
    if (is_array($member)) {
        foreach($member as $name) { 
            if($count > 4) 
                return;
            echo '<p class="top-member-p"><a href="'.$name['profileUrl'].'">'.ucfirst($name['name']).'</a> has '.$name['posts'] . ' posts</p>';
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to get the result sorted on their post count like so:

```
"Swaghetti has 34 posts"<br>
"Josh has 15 posts"<br>
"Test has 3 posts"<br>
"Testuser2 has 0 posts"
```

But instead it goes like this:

```
"Swaghetti has 34 posts"<br>
"Testuser2 has 0 posts"<br>
"Test has 3 posts"<br>
"Josh has 15 posts"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no other option to retreive the data sorted, you can do it yourself - using `usort()` - which is sort by your own function. Compare against the other `posts` values, and place them accordingly in the array (return 1 if it should be moved up, -1 if it should be moved down).

I also added `array_slice()` in, since you appear to only want the first 4 elements (that way you only get those, and no need for a counter).

```php
// Test-data, I guessed my way to your format to match the output from what you had in the question
$data = [
    [['name' => 'Testuser2', 'posts' => 0, 'profileUrl' => 'swag']],
    [['name' => 'Josh', 'posts' => 15, 'profileUrl' => 'swag']],
    [['name' => 'Test', 'posts' => 3, 'profileUrl' => 'swag']],
    [['name' => 'Swaghetti', 'posts' => 34, 'profileUrl' => 'swag']],
];
// $data = json_decode($response, true);

usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    $a = array_column($a[0], 'posts');
    $b = array_column($b[0], 'posts');
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});

$slieced = array_slice($data, 0, 4);
foreach($slieced as $member) {
    if (is_array($member)) {
        foreach($member as $name) {
            echo '<p class="top-member-p">
                      <a href="'.$name['profileUrl'].'">'.ucfirst($name['name']).'</a> 
                      has '.$name['posts'] . ' posts
                  </p>'."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/i9eDB